# Display the size of the input data and input data of integer on arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am writing a program that to Define a new int array of 500 integers to store the input data,also Convert and store the input integers to the array and Display the size of the input data and display the input data as well.

I face the problem that i can't show my input data correctly on the Serial Monitor.For example if i input 123 it will show input data = 3 integers and my input data will become ⸮.But i want myint[0]=123 not myint[0]=1, myint[1]=2, myint[2]=3 so the size should be just count for 1 integers.

I also cannot show what i input the integer on the Serial Monitor.Also how can i not count the space as the size of input data  for example:if i input "123 234" it will just show "Size of input data =  2 integers"

This is the Serial Monitor showing when i input 123:

```
Please input
Size of input data =  3 integers

⸮

Please input
```

Here's my code:

```cpp
int myint[499] ;     // this is an array
char input;
int i;
    
void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    input = Serial.read();
    if (input != '\n') { 
      myint[i++] = input; // last character is newline
      myint[i] = 0;       // string array should be terminated with a zero
    } else{
      input = Convertinteger(input);
      myint[i++] = input;  
      myint[i] = 0;         
      Serial.println("Please input");
      Serial.print("Size of input data =  ");
      Serial.print(i-1);
      Serial.print(" integers");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.print(input);
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("Please input");  
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}

int Convertinteger(char x) {
  if (x <= 0x39 && x >= 0x30)
    return (x - 0x30);
```

Comment: Why not use `Serial.parseInt()` to read numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Serial.print(input);
```

will simply print the value in the input variable. The input variable is a `char` containing `\n` since that's what the `if else` was testing for earlier in the code. If you are wanting to print all three values in your array you will need an too loop through the array printing each value.

Comment: I add that but it show nothing on the Serial Monitor                                                                for (int a = 0; a <= sizeof(myint[i]) ; a = a++) {
        Serial.print(myint[i]);
                               }

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading this I see other issues. You will need two separate arrays. One should be an array of characters (`char`). That would act as a buffer of each character as it is received. Then when you receive the newline (`'\n'`) you should put a 0 in the character buffer instead of the newline. So if you press the keys '1', '3', '8' you will have created the string "138". Then that is your input to Convertinteger. At which point for testing I would print both the input string and the integer output.

Take the output from Convertinteger and store it in your second array which will be an array of `int`. You'll need some way to indicate that your done entering numbers. Maybe just hit enter without entering any numbers. So if after the newline is entered if the first byte of the string is 0 (which is one way to detect an empty string) break out of the loop. Then if you counted 5 number entries you loop 5 times printing them.